# MsTests : Running selective unit tests with specific DataRow Value

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, tdd, integration-testing, xunit

Here is an example of my tests (integration tests for all my environnements) :

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("DEV")]
[DataRow("STAGING")]
[DataRow("PREPROD")]
[DataRow("PROD")]
public void TestMyWebservice(string environnement)
{

}
```

is there any way to execute tests that for example whith only DataRow value ) "STAGING" etc.. so i can runt tests against one environnement on a time.

There is another solution is to duplicate all tests and give the a category and the run test with filtering in the desired category like this :

```
[TestCategory("DEV")]
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("DEV")]
public void TestMyWebservice(string environnement)
{

}

[TestCategory("STAGING")]
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("STAGING")]
public void TestMyWebservice(string environnement)
{

}
```

and the command to filter :

> dotnet test --filter TestCategory=DEV

But i really don"t like it because of duplication and risk to forget some tests in some environnements

Any idea ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try first to use the `.runsettings` method for defining environment variables for running tests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#specify-environment-variables-in-the-runsettings-file

So theoretically, you'd have different files for your different environments:

- dev.runsettings
- staging.runsettings
- preprod.runsettings
- prod.runsettings

... which might look something like this (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65667284/13864681):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <ENV>DEV</ENV>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Then, depending on how you setup your environment in code, you could do something like this in the `[AssemblyInitialize]` method in your test project(s):

```
[TestClass]
public class Config
{
    // this method will run before any TestMethod in your project
    // and can be used to define project-wide configurations
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENV");
        // ... use 'env' to set your environment settings
    }
}
```

Then, you can define your tests normally, without specifying their environment.

And finally, run from the command line:

```
dotnet test --settings dev.runsettings
dotnet test --settings staging.runsettings
dotnet test --settings preprod.runsettings
dotnet test --settings prod.runsettings
```