# How to use environment variables in unit tests (.net core)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, mstest

I have got a method that I am trying to test which uses environment variables from my "local.settings.json"

```
private static string _environmentVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("envirnomentVarConfig");

public string MyMethod()
{
    var result = DoStuff(_environmentVar)
    return result;  
}
```

In my test I am calling this method and when debugging, I can see that _environmentVar is null.

Do I need to setup envirnomentVarConfig in the test? If so how?

Comment: Why do you think local.settings.json is going to be read and populated into an environment variable?

Comment: I expected it to read it because when the test calls that method, the GetEnvironmentVariable is hit before the method, leading me to beleive it would go and get that variable from the setings json. clearly not

Comment: I'm just curious why you think that putting something in a .json file is going to lead to it becoming an environment variable. It's not impossible - you could have some code you're not showing us that does just that. But it's not going to do it out of the box. If you need to read configuration from a file, you need to use a specialized class that does just that. Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable doesn't do that.

Comment: It works when running the code normally?

Comment: You mean when running the application not as a unit test? Do you have additional code there that reads the configuration? Perhaps in a Startup.cs file?

Comment: I've not got any additional code that i'm aware of. No startup file or anything

Comment: Then how would the app know about your local.settings.json file? Did you look at Program.cs, in the main method? What does that call? If this is an ASP.NET Core app, you're setting up the configuration somewhere most likely, especially if you used the built in templates to create the app.

Comment: The method mentioned, when run normally, is called by an azure function(using the given template)

Comment: Hang on - so this is an Azure Function? Not ASP.NET Core web application? Why did you tag it as ASP.NET Core then?

Comment: the issue isn't in the function. it's in my core class library

Answer (score 36):

Solved this by setting up the variable in the test using:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("environmentVarConfig", "environmentVarValue");
```

Comment: Just a note: May not work for machine wide variables that needs restart

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me (using XUnit + .net5) so I made a wrapper class & interface which I then mocked...

Comment: Working for xunit on a local laptop

Comment: This has side effects for further tests

Comment: Works on .net6. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can [specify environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#specify-environment-variables-in-the-runsettings-file) in the `.runsettings` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <YOUR_VARIABLE>Value for your variable</YOUR_VARIABLE>
            <SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE>With another Value</SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Alternatively you can [implement](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/extensions/datacollector.md#datacollection-environment-variables) a `DataCollector` which provides environment variables via `ITestExecutionEnvironmentSpecifier`

```cs
// Add a reference to nuget package `Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel`
// The assembly name must end with `Collector` (i.e. match `*collector.dll`)

[DataCollectorFriendlyName("my own example collector")]
[DataCollectorTypeUri("datacollector://myown/examplecollector/1.0")]
public class MyDataCollector : DataCollector, ITestExecutionEnvironmentSpecifier
{
    public override void Initialize(
        XmlElement configurationElement,
        DataCollectionEvents events,
        DataCollectionSink dataSink,
        DataCollectionLogger logger,
        DataCollectionEnvironmentContext environmentContext)
    {
        // inspect configurationElement for your custom settings
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetTestExecutionEnvironmentVariables()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["YOUR_VARIABLE"] = "your value",
        };
    }
}
```

You also configure your data collector via the `.runsettings` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <TestAdaptersPaths>path/where/to/find/your/collector</TestAdaptersPaths>
    </RunConfiguration>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="my own example collector" uri="datacollector://myown/examplecollector/1.0">
                <Configuration>
                    <SomeSettingHere/>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: I've added `.runsettings`  in the project root directory, not in the solution. It didn't work until I manually pointed the location of the file. `Test explorer > settings (cog icon) > Configure run settings > Select solution wide .runsettings file.`

Comment: The documentation I linked gives [various ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#specify-a-run-settings-file-in-the-ide) how you can set up VS to pick up the `.runsettings` file

Comment: Note this only works on Windows at the moment as the macOS Visual Studio doesn't yet support runsettings files.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it globally for tests on WebHostBuilder according to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-environment

```
protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder() =>
       base.CreateWebHostBuilder().UseEnvironment("Testing");
```